# Is this special matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

The symmetric, tridiagonal $n-$by$-n$ matrix with the elements $a_{ii+1} = a_{i+1i} $ and off-diagonals' absolute values equal to the diagonal (except for row 1 and row n) is invertible. The elements on the diagonal are nonzero.

How can I go about showing this? Row reducing and finding the determinant would be too long.

Comment: See the (recursive) formula for the determinant given [here](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant).

Comment: Note that it suffices to check in the case that all (non-zero) entries are $1$.

Comment: @omnomnomnom why?

Comment: @DonLarynx that would you could find the determinant, and thereby check if the matrix is invertible.

Comment: Or do you mean my second point?  Note that
$$
\det[aM] = a^n \det M
$$
for any number $a$ and matrix $M$.

Comment: @DonLarynx oh, I misunderstood what you meant in your description of the matrix

Comment: One way to know that a matrix is not invertible is to check and see if any of its columns (or rows) can be written as a linear combination of other columns (or rows). If one of the columns (or rows) is linearly dependent (i.e. can be written as a combination of other columns (or rows)), then the matrix is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider
$$
A_n:=\mathrm{tridiag}(1,1,1),
$$
that is, a tridiagonal matrix with constant entries on the three diagonals.
Clearly, these matrices satisfy the given conditions.
The eigenvalues of $A_n$ are
$$
1+2\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n+1}\right), \quad k=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Hence, for any $n=3m-1$, $m=1,2,\ldots$, $A_n$ is singular.

Comment: Just to give a very concrete example: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is singular.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I know. Since in OP, there is a certain ignorance of what is going on in the first and last rows, the point of this "exercise" was to point out also some nontrivial cases :-)

Comment: I'm not saying you don't know (it's obvious from your answer that you did), I just wanted to make clear to everyone what the counterexample was by writing down an explicit matrix.